# ASP.NET C# (3.5), Membership, how to set RoleName using a DropDownList in a GridView?

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu, membership

I try to set "RoleName" using a DropDownList in a GridView, but I get this error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'RoleName'.
```

I've done whatever you imagine, mentioned in different forums.
Here are the codes:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" PageSize="25" CssClass="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UserName" DataSourceID="odsUsersInRoles" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsRoles" DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="RoleName" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("RoleName") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsRoles" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllRolesButAdministrator" TypeName="cUsers"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RoleName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ...
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


public static string[] GetAllRolesButAdministrator()
{
    string[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
    int removeIndex = Array.IndexOf(roles, "Administrator");

    if (removeIndex >= 0)
    {
        string[] newStrItems = new string[roles.Length - 1];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < newStrItems.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            if (i == removeIndex)
                j++;
            newStrItems[i] = roles[j];
        }

        roles = newStrItems;
    }
    return roles;
}
```

Please someone help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had done a very stupid mistake :-(

The row I was trying to set its RoleName, did not had a Role at all, so it could not bind the 'null' to any of the roles.

The problem is fixed :-)